# Where are downloaded sound files saved?

Tags: iphone

When I download a sound file in my iPhone, in which directory is it stored?

Comment: what is downloaded sound file directory in iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'sound file directory'.

Safari cannot download files to the iPhone and if you download a sound file from code you will receive the data in an `NSData` object. From there it is up to you where you write the file (or even *if* you write a file, you could use the data without saving it). However you will still not have many options on where to save the file because of the iPhone sandbox.